# c++ polymorphism and other function question

Tags: c++, polymorphism

i have got this code:

```
class father{
public:
    virtual void f() { cout<<1;}
};

class son:public father{
public:
    void f() {cout<<2;}
};

void test (father x){x.f();}

int main(){
    son s;
    test(s);
}
```

the question says:

1. the output is '1', what is the rule about polymorphism that the programmer forgot and how can i fix it so the output would be '2'?
2. there is another rule that the programmer forgot when he wrote the father class, and he need to add an empty function to avoid problems from other sons of the father class. what is the rule and what is the missing function?

---

another question
write the g function so the next code would run with no crashes

```
int x=11; g(x)=22;
```

Comment: I think we can safely say - homework.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like homework, if that is the case please tag it as such.

Comment: it's not H.W i finished this course a long time ago, but someone want me to solve this question and i didn't know....

Comment: @aharont: Maybe it isn't **your** homework, but it surely is someone's homework

Comment: I know you didn't choose your book/question, but I find the use of "parent/child", "father/son" in inheritance examples makes them more confusing than they otherwise would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass the `son` object to the test function by value, it will be converted to a `father` object because `test` takes a `father`, not a `son`. If you want to accept instances of subclass without conversion, you need to accept the argument by reference or pointer.

So if you change the signature of `test` to `void test (father& x)`, it will work as you want.

Comment: ok. and what is the other problem in this class (the function that need to add)

Comment: and why would i need virtual distructor?

Comment: Because the presence of a virtual function in the base class indicates that there will be code out there somewhere using a base pointer that actually points to a derived object. You want to be sure when that pointer is deleted that the derived destructor gets a chance to clean up any resources that are specific to the derived object (ie weren't inherited from the base.)

Answer (score 2):

I tell my C++ students (in second year) that polymorphism will never sneak up on them; first you need an inheritance hierarchy, and second you need to be using pointers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Pass **son** s to **test** as a reference, rather than a copy.  If s is passed as a copy, it will be cast to a **father** object in **test**.  By using a reference of s instead, it will still behave, properly, as a **son** object.
2. I think this is referring to the recommendation that any base class should have a virtual destructor.  That way, the object can be properly destroyed through a pointer or reference of its base class.

add to **father**:

virtual ~father() {}

Answer (score 1):

You passed x by value. So the compiler will reduce the son object to a father object, including its virtual function table. If you want to call a virtual function of father in test, you need to pass x either by reference or by pointer.

Answer (score 0):

What is it about the test function that makes you think the output would be 2?

Comment: Indeed, and I was trying to hint at what, but whether it's homework or not you have your answer

Answer (score 0):

In the function "test" the parameter "father x" is not a reference to class, it IS an instance of father that will be copy constructed from the passed parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Well u could also make some changes in ur main regarding this problem like making pointer to your base class I.e father and point it to address of ur child class obj then further use that as per ur requirement.

This is what the basic structure of polymorphism.